# DevExpress - CheckedBoxListControl.Add(DictionaryValue, "") - How can I get Dictionary back?

Tags: c#, devexpress

Let's just say someone needed to place a Dictionary into a CheckedBoxListControl for usage down the road. Let's also say this person was having issues getting their hands back on said dictionary. Here's some code:

```
private void populateCheckListBox()
    {
        // Create new dictionary<int, string>
        Dictionary<int, string> dictEmpInfo = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        foreach (DataTable dt in _dsEmployee.Tables)
        {
            // Check table name
            if (dt.TableName == "EmployeeInfo")
            {
                // Iterate through row, get employee name and ID
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string fullName = dr[1].ToString();
                    int empID = (int)dr[0];

                    dictEmpInfo.Add(empID, fullName);

                    // Assign items to checkedboxlist
                    clbEmployees.Items.Add(dictEmpInfo, fullName);
                }
            }               
        }            
    }
```

I, *cough cough*, er um, this person needed to set string values of fullName to the CheckedBoxList and then also down the road utilize the IDs of these employees. Would anyone have any suggestions as to how to get this data back out? My friend thanks you.

Comment: I forgot to mention I traversed through intellisense to a property called 'fValue' which seemed to contain all the data I needed. I just don't know how to get the data from it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Didn't see that a .value property already existed, so I just needed to cast it back to a dictionary after I iterated through the list of checked items. Here's what I did:

```
foreach (CheckedListBoxItem item in clbEmployees.CheckedItems)
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            dict = (Dictionary<int, string>)item.Value;
        }
```